# Getting intermittent Internal 500 errror while hitting the URL in Web Browser

Tags: apache, weblogic11g, siteminder

The page is loading intermittently,Loading for 15 minutes again its start throwing Error,When we checked the Webserv logs we found below webgent error.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

> ][CSmLowLevelAgent.cpp:492][ERROR] LLA: SiteMinder Agent Api function
>   failed - 'Sm_AgentApi_IsProtectedEx' returned '-1'.
>
> [16173/1915251008][Thu Jul 23 2015
>   00:24:19][CSmProtectionManager.cpp:192][ERROR] HLA: Component reported
>   fatal error: 'Low Level Agent'.
>
> [16173/1915251008][Thu Jul 23 2015
>   00:24:19][CSmHighLevelAgent.cpp:376][ERROR] HLA: Component reported
>   fatal error: 'Protection Manager'.

PS

When I am hitting the  URL’s continuously for 10-15 min, the page loads without any problem,  roughly after 16 -17 min the  page stops loading and throwing internal server error. Then again after some time it loads automatically.

I  observe the below error hitting continuously in the logs then I still have issues for the webagent to communicate to the policy server.

> [16173/3669576000][Wed Jul 22 2015
>   22:08:51][CSmProtectionManager.cpp:192][ERROR] HLA: Component reported
>   fatal error: 'Low Level Agent'. [16173/3669576000][Wed Jul 22 2015
>   22:08:51][CSmHighLevelAgent.cpp:376][ERROR] HLA: Component reported
>   fatal error: 'Protection Manager'. [16173/3711535424][Wed Jul 22 2015
>   22:08:51][CSmLowLevelAgent.cpp:492][ERROR] LLA: SiteMinder Agent Api
>   function failed - 'Sm_AgentApi_IsProtectedEx' returned '-1'.

These errors comes first in the logs and eventually after a minute your page also throws out internal server error.

Comment: Added the details as requested.Kindly help me its urgent..

Comment: please edit your post to add content from these additional log files: smps.log, smtracedefault.log, webagent trace log. please label which logs come from which logs.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Those error logs generally mean the communication between WebAgent and Policy Server does not work.

Please should confirm that 44440 - 44445 ports were open.